# bs4dash show all tooltips (without hover) when header help == TRUE

Tags: r, shiny, bs4dash

`bs4dash::dashboardPage` has the [`help` option](https://rinterface.github.io/bs4Dash/reference/dashboardPage.html) that shows on the page header and, when toggled to TRUE, allows tooltips to show when hovering over the element. When toggled to FALSE, tooltips never show. I would like to change the tooltip behavior so that when the header help option is toggled to TRUE, users see all the tooltips/popovers at the same time, and they all stay up until the user toggles the help option off again. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you also have a question?

Comment: How do I do what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

The `bs4Dash` help switch value (TRUE or FALSE) is stored in `input$help_switch`. Instead of showing a bunch of individual tooltips, I ended up just showing a modal popup for the whole page. Here's an example:

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)

shinyApp(
    ui = dashboardPage(
        header = dashboardHeader(
            title = dashboardBrand(
                title = "My dashboard",
                color = "primary",
                href = "https://adminlte.io/themes/v3",
                image = "https://adminlte.io/themes/v3/dist/img/AdminLTELogo.png"
            )
        ),
        sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
            bs4Dash::sidebarMenu(
                id = "sidebarmenu",
                bs4Dash::menuItem(
                    text = "Tab 1",
                    tabName = "tab1"
                ),
                bs4Dash::menuItem(
                    text = "Tab 2",
                    tabName = "tab2"
                ))
        ),
        body = dashboardBody(
            bs4Dash::tabItems(
                bs4Dash::tabItem(
                    tabName = "tab1",
                    lapply(getAdminLTEColors()[1:3], function(color) {
                        box(status = color)
                        })
                ),
                bs4Dash::tabItem(
                    tabName = "tab2",
                    lapply(getAdminLTEColors()[4:7], function(color) {
                        box(status = color)
                    })
                )
        )),
        controlbar = dashboardControlbar(),
        title = "DashboardPage"
    ),
    server = function(input, output) { 
        shiny::observe({
            if(input$help_switch == TRUE){
                if(input$sidebarmenu == "tab1"){
                    shiny::showModal(
                        ui = shiny::modalDialog(
                            title = "About this app",
                            "This is an important message for tab 1!"
                        ))
                } else if(input$sidebarmenu == "tab2"){
                    shiny::showModal(
                        ui = shiny::modalDialog(
                            title = "About this app",
                            "This is an important message for tab 2!"
                        ))
                }
            }
        })
    }
)
```

[image: gif showing dashboard]